# How to get "stronger" simplifications of conjunctions in Z3?

Tags: z3

Using Z3 version 2.18, I am trying to simplify formulas such as:

- (and (> (- (- x 1) 1) 0) (> x 0))
- (or (> (- (- x 1) 1) 0) (> x 0))

hoping to get something like: (> x 2) and (> x 0).

I am running Z3 with the following input file where F is one of the above formulas:

```
(set-option set-param "STRONG_CONTEXT_SIMPLIFIER" "true")
(declare-const x Int)
(simplify F)
```

It works well with the disjunction where I get the following output:

```
(let (($x35 (<= x 0)))
(not $x35))
```

However, with the conjunction, I get:

```
(not (or (<= x 0) (<= x 2)))
```

Is there a way to force Z3 to simplify even more the above formula ? I would hope to be able to get `(not (<= x 2))`.

PS: Is there a way to force Z3 to inline its output (i.e. having `(not (<= x 0))` instead of `(let (($x35 (<= x 0))) (not $x35))`)

Thanks,
Gus

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't do that on Z3 2.x.

Z3 3.x has a new (fully compliant) SMT 2.0 front-end.
Z3 3.x has several new features such as a "strategy specification language" based on tactics and tacticals. I'm not "advertising" that yet because it is working in progress. The basic idea is described in this [slide deck](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/leonardo/cp2011.pdf). This language can be used to do what you want. You just have to write:

```
(declare-const x Int)
(assert (not (or (<= x 0) (<= x 2))))
(apply (and-then simplify propagate-bounds))
```

You can find all available tactics by using the commands:

```
(help-strategy)
(help apply)
(help check-sat-using)
```